# Webpack Require String Replacement

Tags: node.js, webpack

Is it possible to allow a global variable as evaluated expression in **webpack require**?

For Example:

```
global.root = path.join(__dirname, 'abc/');

var x = require(root + 'x-module')
```

Or is it possible to replace 'root + \'' to any string before webpack resolves the path? such as

```
require(root + 'x-module')   --->    require('../abc/x-module')
```

Comment: Any packer that uses the require strings to determine what to pack, will not be able to determine what module that require referers to.

Comment: @DanD. is it possible to replace all 'root + \'' to certain path before webpack resolves a string in require?

Comment: might this help? https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use string-replace-loader to resolve this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader